# Load testing with Kafka and Storm

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, jmeter, apache-storm

Our system takes post request and send json body to kafka topic and this topic is configured as spout for topology and topology generate output message to a kafka topic.
How i can load test this system? Number of message processed per second by system.

I am planning to use jmeter for load testing

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is the one which comes in our mind whenever we think about performance or load testing of Web APIs, however you can also check for alternatives like LoadRunner etc.

However, from Kafka and Storm point of view, you need to write storm kafka spout to read and commit offsets as well as you might need some monitoring tool to check and validate how it behaves under load like

- Throughput (messages/sec) on size of data.
- Throughput (messages/sec) on number of messages.
- Performance at Producer side
- Performance at Consumer side

I've tried Yahoo Kafka manager which is opensource and serves the purpose, might want give it a try: https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager, however there other monitoring tools also [Kafka Monitoring tool in Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49043596/kafka-monitoring-tool-in-production)

If you want focus only Kafka load performance benchmarking then below command under your kafka distribution would be very helpful:

- kafka-producer-perf-test.sh
- kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh

For more details: https://gist.github.com/ueokande/b96eadd798fff852551b80962862bfb3

Comment: Thanks for info!! basically kafka topic is just output storage  for us,basically we want to benchmark our storm topology, So we want to stress our topology.how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use JMeter it makes sense to consider [Pepper-Box - Kafka Load Generator](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box) plugin, it comes with [PepperBoxKafkaSampler](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box#pepperboxkafkasampler) which provides handy UI allowing to specify your Kafka endpoints, topics, etc.

[image]

If you need also to read messages from the Kafka topics you can use [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and Groovy language for this, check out [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter/) and [Writing a Kafka Consumer in Java](https://dzone.com/articles/writing-a-kafka-consumer-in-java) articles for more information and example code snippets

Comment: Thanks, But actually i can use post API to post messages to topic as producer but we want to load test our apache storm topologies