# Load testing kafka with multiple producers and multiple consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, load-testing

I am trying to load test my Kafka cluster with multiple producers and multiple consumers. I came across a lot of available tools and article but all of them generates load(Producer) from a single machine and similarly reads(Consumer) from a single machine.

I am looking for a tool which can be deployed across/spawn multiple producers and consumers and load test a given kafka cluster.

- As input, we can give the number of producers and consumers.
- It can then spawn those number of machines with producers and consumers (On AWS, Azure or GCP). Or we can spawn machines manually and then the tool can initiate producer and consumer on them.
- Post that it load test's the target kafka cluster.
- At the end, it gives out test results like, write/sec, read/sec etc.

Tools/Articles I checked are:

- https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter
- https://medium.com/selectstarfromweb/lets-load-test-kafka-f90b71758afb
- [Load testing with Kafka and Storm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58982753/load-testing-with-kafka-and-storm)
- [Load test kafka consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66248486/load-test-kafka-consumer)
- [Load testing a kafka consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61873279/load-testing-a-kafka-consumer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [very first article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter) neither mentions nor assumes any limitations regarding the number of consumers/producers.

Just put the [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) for different Kafka instances (or different topics or whatever is your test scenario) under different JMeter [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) and you will be able to concurrently stress multiple endpoints.

If you prefer doing it from different machines - you can [run JMeter in distributed mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter) and point different JMeter slave machines to stress different endpoints using [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) and [__machineName()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineName) or [__machineIP()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__machineIP) functions combination.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It seems that this should work, however, I had a doubt. How will we be able to get the metrics like, read/sec and write/sec? Every machine or thread will produce it's own metrics. 

I am looking for a tool that can give me a consolidated result of all the producer and consumer instances.

Comment: When you run JMeter in distributed mode all the test results are aggregated in the master machine so you will have a single [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) which can be opened with a [Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-listeners-part-3-listeners-calculate-distribution-metrics) of your choice of you can generate an [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) out of it.